# MySQL Center Average Over Three Year Interval for Distinct Un-ordered Record Values

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+------+-----------+
|  make  |  model   | year | avg_price |
+--------+----------+------+-----------+
| Subaru | Forester | 2013 |     18533 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2014 |     27284 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2010 |     18296 |
| Subaru | Forester | 2012 |     16589 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2013 |     25330 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2011 |     20366 |
| Subaru | Forester | 2008 |      7256 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2015 |     33519 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2012 |     23033 |
| Subaru | Forester | 2011 |     15789 |
+--------+----------+------+-----------+
```

Using MySQL, I want to add a new column with a three year average price centered on the record year. It should look like this when done:

```
+--------+----------+------+-----------+---------------------+
|  make  |  model   | year | avg_price | 3_yr_center_average |
+--------+----------+------+-----------+---------------------+
| Subaru | Forester | 2013 |     18533 |               17561 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2014 |     27284 |               28711 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2010 |     18296 |               19331 |
| Subaru | Forester | 2012 |     16589 |               16970 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2013 |     25330 |               25216 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2011 |     20366 |               20565 |
| Subaru | Forester | 2008 |      7256 |                7256 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2015 |     33519 |               30401 |
| Ford   | F-150    | 2012 |     23033 |               22910 |
| Subaru | Forester | 2011 |     15789 |               16189 |
+--------+----------+------+-----------+---------------------+
```

It seems that this should be straight forward if the data was ordered and everything was the same make and model. The reality is the working table has over 4000 unique make model year combinations and they are all un-ordered by year.

Therefore, the query cannot rely on ordered records or that adjacent records are in any way relevant to the next record. The query needs to filter on the distinct make model and year then center avg over the three year interval without hiccuping when it is averaging the first or last year of a spread where it will be missing one or two of the three years.

Any MySQL tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try joining twice to bring the previous and proceeding years into a single line with the current year, for each make and model.  Then, subquery and take the average of prices from the three years:

```
SELECT make, model, year, avg_price,
    (avg_price + last_price + next_price) / (1.0 + last_cnt + next_cnt) AS 3_yr_center_average
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.make, t1.model, t1.year, t1.avg_price,
        COALESCE(t2.avg_price, 0) AS last_price,
        COALESCE(t3.avg_price, 0) AS next_price,
        CASE WHEN t2.avg_price IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS last_cnt,
        CASE WHEN t3.avg_price IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS next_cnt
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.make = t2.make AND t1.model = t2.model AND t1.year = t2.year + 1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t3
        ON t1.make = t3.make AND t1.model = t3.model AND t1.year = t3.year - 1
) t
ORDER BY
    make, model, year;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that there is an edge case here in your data with regard to what should happen for a record which is the last (or first) year for that make and model.  In that case, there are only two years available for the three year moving average.  I made the assumption in this case that you would be OK with actually just reporting a *two year* moving average.  For example, for the Subaru Forester in 2013, I report a three year moving average of `17561`, which is actually the average of the 2013 price `18533` and the previous 2012 price `16589`.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Biegeleisen, this was exactly it. I did modify your code to use the -1 on t2.year and +1 on t3.year to stay in sync with your last_price and next_price naming convention.

Comment: @user3034910 Check my updated answer.  I added support such that for years on the boundaries (i.e. the first and last years for a model and make), we report a _two_ year average, the third year not being available.